# Can i migrate safety from angular 6 to angular 9?

Tags: angular

Do i need to update my angular project from **6 to 7** and so on or I can update it straight to the latest version of angular

Comment: what is it that you do? Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides documentation on migrations. Plenty of it. I think jumping from 6 to 9 will be pretty painful since there are some breaking changes in there, but you could probably do it.

This is a good guide to follow: https://update.angular.io/

More specifically: https://update.angular.io/#6.0:9.0

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a guide to go from versions, in the case of going from version 6 to 9 it marks a warning, although the guide says for basic applications.

[Link Guide angular](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:9.0)